# second level ember route not rendering

Tags: javascript, ember.js, ember-data

I've been having a good deal of trouble recently trying to get sub templates to render in Ember.  The jsbin below doesn't work because I'm trying to use the REST adapter and just can't figure it out how to get mockjax and ember working together -- anyway, I think the REST adapter critical to the problem, as I will explain.

So I have a contact item.  I can see ember calling my /api/contacts route to grab the model for all the contacts for listing.  After this, I'm trying to create a link to an individual contact and have that render within the same template.  In other words, I would still see the list of contacts, but I also see information on the individual contact that I just clicked on.  That individual contact contains many contactPoints.  Basically, what's happening is that I never see ember looking for the contactPoints.  I see the "contact" template render, but it never has any contactPoints.

If this unclear, I can clarify.  But the link below should help.  Thanks!

http://emberjs.jsbin.com/xacuyalu/6/edit

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've simplified a bit your JsBin to highlight the solution

http://emberjs.jsbin.com/xacuyalu/7

With what you are trying to achieve, there's no need to name outlets.

The main problem in your code is the way you use variables inside loops and templates.
In your `contacts` template, you write

```
{{#each contact}}
```

But then forget to use `contact` as a variable when passing values

The same way, in your `contact` template, you use `contactItem` that doesn't exist. You can simply use the attribute of your model here.

The problem with `mockajax` was the url you were mocking `/api/contacts` instead of `/contacts`. This works in my modified JsBin.

Also please note that your payload won't work with `contactPoints`

EDIT: I've updated the JsBin to display the contact points.

http://emberjs.jsbin.com/xacuyalu/9

First thing, I would recommend you to read this https://github.com/emberjs/data/blob/master/TRANSITION.md. It will show you how to prepare your data to work nicely with Ember Data.

I have extracted your payload to be more readable. Here are the things that I've done:

- Sideload contact points
- Change the name of the attribute in the json from `contactPointsIds`
  to `contactPoints`
- add the `address` attribute on the `ContactPoint` model
- Rename the attribute on the `Contact` model from `contactPoint` to
  `contactPoints`

Comment: Thanks Cyril; appreciate the help in getting the example working on jsbin.  I'm curious about why the sideloaded contactPoints don't work.  See the contact template which is supposed to loop through and list the address attribute in each contactPoint.  What am I missing to get that working?  That's my main objective here.

Comment: I've updated my answer and the JsBin to display the contact points.